# Aria-checked value not switching from true to false when checking the checkbox

Tags: angularjs, html, checkbox, angularjs-directive, wai-aria

My screen reader **JAWS 17** is reading Checkbox not checked when I am on the checkbox even though I check it.

I debugged the issue and found out that the **aria-checked="false"** is not switching to **aria-checked="true"** when I check it.

I am using Google Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

HTML

```
<modified-input
         enter-space-press="checked(row)"
         disabled="!row.enabled"
         ng-click="check(row)">
 </modified-input>
```

Directive

```
function modifiedInput($window, $rootScope, _) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                value:'=?',
                disabled:'=?',
            },
            template: (
                '<input ' +
                'type="checkbox" ' +
                'ng-disabled="disabled" ' +
                'aria-checked= "false" ' +
                'ng-value="value"/>'
            ),

        };
    }

    modifiedInput.$inject = ["$window", "$rootScope", '_'];
    module.exports = modifiedInput;
```

Comment: You don't need to manually handle aria-checked on a native checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ngAria in your project. It should handle common aria attributes automatically.

Read the [official documentation here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/accessibility)

See [working plunker here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/USU7whlPhsuW4KU3xwUR?p=preview)

Based on the documentation, if you include ngAria in your project and use ng-model, the aria attributes will be handled automatically.

I'd suggest changing the template to this:

```
    template: (
        '<input ' +
        'type="checkbox" ' +
        'ng-disabled="disabled" ' +
        'ng-value="value" ' +
        'ng-model="checked"/>'
    )
```

Comment: Hi thank you fort the answering but I am using it. And its not working

Comment: Hi, Can you please check this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/USU7whlPhsuW4KU3xwUR?p=preview

Comment: Based on the documentation, if use ng-model, ngAria should handle the aria attributes automatically. I'll update the answer with this

Comment: I added it but it is still not working. I'll play around with this and see. Thank you though